# Live feed update plot with bokeh

Tags: python, time-series, bokeh, live-streaming

I have a data file that updates every 5 minutes with new data. I import this data with pandas (index = date and time and then two columns of data) and then plot it in a timeseries. I need a way for the plots on the html to refresh and update automatically every time more data is added to the file. This would be best if it could do it when the column length gets longer but also just every 5 minutes would be great.

```
rubble = pd.read_csv('/TURB1.dat', usecols=['TIMESTAMP','TSS_shallow_corr_Med', 'TSS_deep_corr_Med',], skiprows=[2,3], na_values=['-'], index_col=0, parse_dates=True, header=1)

inshore = pd.read_csv('/TURB1_App.dat', usecols=['TIMESTAMP', 'TSS_shallow_corr_Med', 'TSS_deep_corr_Med',], skiprows=[2,3], na_values=['-'], index_col=0, parse_dates=True, header=1)

output_file("layout.html", title='Subtech Turbidity Data')
TOOLS="hover,crosshair,pan,wheel_zoom,box_zoom,reset,tap,save,box_select,poly_select,lasso_select"
```

## create the plots

```
rubble_day = TimeSeries(rubble, ylabel='mg/l', xlabel='TIME', width=750, height=500, title='Rubble Buoy', legend=True, tools=TOOLS)

inshore_day = TimeSeries(inshore[-1440:], ylabel='mg/l', xlabel='TIME', width=750, height=500, title='Inshore Buoy', legend=True, tools=TOOLS)

rubble_hour = TimeSeries(rubble[-60:], ylabel='mg/l', xlabel='TIME', width=500, height=500, title='Rubble Buoy', legend=True, tools=TOOLS)

inshore_hour = TimeSeries(inshore[-60:], ylabel='mg/l', xlabel='TIME', width=500, height=500, title='Inshore Buoy', legend=True, tools=TOOLS)

p = gridplot([[rubble_day, rubble_hour], [inshore_day, inshore_hour]])

show(p)
```

Any help would be much appreciated!!!!

Comment: This sounds like a perfect use-case for a Bokeh server application. There are several [live examples](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/gallery.html) that you can study and emulate, as well as [extensive documentation](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html)  on the main documentation site

Comment: @bigreddot Hi yes I know Bokeh does seem perfect, I have looked through all the examples and I cant get them to work for my data... any help would be really appreciated!!

Comment: This would probably require some "back and forth" discussion, so I'd suggest coming by the project mailing list instead. SO frowns upon such collaborative discussions, which it considers "not an answer". I will say though, that a few general tips: it's usually more effective to replace data, not whole plots, in which case I'd also suggest `bokeh.plotting` instead of `bokeh.charts`

Comment: @bigreddot ok I am not familiar with project mailing list can you please provide a link, many thanks

Comment: Sure, it's a google group: https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/?pli=1#!forum/bokeh